# Where can I find a tutorial or sample code for the Juniper WiFi Arduino Shield?

Tags: arduino, electronics, wifi

I recently got an arduino wifi shield known as "juniper" (I believe it was by cutedigi). I've tried to find code examples, but when I saw code, it was un-commented and very little explained, I could really use a tutorial or some sample code with a good explanation, can anyone help me find a place to start? I found a piece of code here: http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=103582.0
and I just want to connect to a network, maybe send some get requests, or open a socket.

EDIT:
after poking around for a while, i found documentation, but I still can't get it to work.
my code:
http://pastie.org/5455603
I can't seem to get any input at all from the wifi shield.

Comment: Can you be more specific regarding what you need the code to do? It might also help to post an example of the code you found as we may be able to help explain what it is doing. Don't forget to supply attribution if you do of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best ally will be Google. A quick search for "arduino juniper cutedigi" led me to the [manufacturer's website](http://www.cutedigi.com/wireless/wifi/juniper-wifi-shield-for-arduino-based-on-gainspan-module.html), which includes a good amount of documentation and sample code under the "Download:" heading at the end of the page. Here's an extra [troubleshooting forum post](http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,118268.0.html) that may be of use.

Even if you don't find the best documented code out there, finding several sample scripts that do similar things might help you understand the basics.

Comment: I did that, and it worked excellently, thank you